# Typescript based React: importScripts() gives: 'importScripts' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, typescript, workbox

Following Google Workbox instructions, the first thing I am told I should include in **serviceWorker.js** is:

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js');
```

But trying to run **npm run start** gives me:

```
importScripts' is not defined  no-undef
```

Where exactly does importScripts get defined usually, and how would I emnable using it in a Typescript-based React project made (and not ejected) with Create React App 2?

Comment: I think you might need to add `WebWorker` to [TypeScripts `tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) `lib` property.

Answer (score 3):

Add `WebWorker` within `lib` property of `compilerOptions` in *tsconfig.json* file. Example

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ... 
    "lib": [
      ...,
      "WebWorker"
    ]
  }
}
```

P.S. After making changes, restart your IDE. Although this is not required but in most cases, it works :)

Answer (score 0):

[`importScripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts) is defined for worker scripts, including [web workers](https://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) (both dedicated [`new Worker`] and shared [`new SharedWorker`]) and [service workers](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/). If it's not defined in your case, it sounds like the script being run isn't being run in one of those ways.